# How Do I Move Objects Inside An ng-Repeat on Button Click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nifty list of items in an ng-repeat with an up and down button on each. I just want the up button to move the list item up one place and the down button should move it down one place.
The problem is that I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined."
It seems "position" is undefined on the second line. What can I do to fix that?

Heres the javascript I'm working with (thanks to Rishul Matta):

```
$scope.moveUp = function(ind, position) {
       $scope.temp = $scope.list[position - 1];
       $scope.list[position - 1] = $scope.list[position];
       $scope.list[position = temp];
  };
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="steps" ng-repeat="step in selectedWorkflow.Steps track by $index" ng-class="{'words' : step.Id != selectedStep.Id, 'selectedWords' : step.Id == selectedStep.Id}" ng-model="selectedWorkflow.Step" ng-click="selectStep(step, $index); toggleShow('showSubStep'); toggleShow('showEditBtn')">
      {{step.Name}}
      <input class="orderUpBtn" type="button" ng-click="moveUp($index, step)" style="z-index:50" value="U" />
      <input class="orderDownBtn" type="button" style="z-index:50" value="D" /> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: That is what I tried. I get an error saying "cannot read property NaN of undefined."

Comment: So you need to put that in your question. jsfiddles help a lot as well. What you want to avoid is just dropping some code and saying "how do I do this?" Here are some more tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok i made it more specific. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for posting this question (+1) and the answer jtrussell (+1). I wanted to share what I believe to be a more re-usable/modular answer for other folks (inspired by [odetocode.com post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/17/the-special-properties-of-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.aspx)).

For the HTML, jtrussell's code is perfect because he fixed/simplified everything. For a better user experience I just added ng-disabled for the first/last elements.

**HTML:**

```
<ul ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
    <li ng-repeat="item in demo.list">
        {{item}}
        <button class="move-up"
            ng-click="listItemUp($index)"
            ng-disabled="$first">
                Move Up
        </button>
        <button class="move-down"
            ng-click="listItemDown($index)"
            ng-disabled="$last">
            Move Down
    </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For the JS, Notice the moveItem() function which I believe to be more re-usable. You can use this function for other drag+drop swapping functionality as well.

**JS within Controller (tested on Angular 1.3.15):**

```
// Move list items up or down or swap
$scope.moveItem = function (origin, destination) {
    var temp = $scope.list[destination];
    $scope.list[destination] = $scope.list[origin];
    $scope.list[origin] = temp;
};

// Move list item Up
$scope.listItemUp = function (itemIndex) {
    $scope.moveItem(itemIndex, itemIndex - 1);
};

// Move list item Down
$scope.listItemDown = function (itemIndex) {
    $scope.moveItem(itemIndex, itemIndex + 1);
};
```

I hope it is helpful to someone out there. Thanks SO community!

Answer (score 3):

A simple list with up/down buttons is pretty straightforward, here's some rough generic code. The `ngRepeat` directive will honor the order of items in your array so moving things around the view is just a matter of moving them in the array itself.

view:

```
<ul ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
  <li ng-repeat="item in demo.list">
    {{item}}
    <button ng-click="demo.moveUp($index)">up</button>
    <button ng-click="demo.moveDown($index)">down</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  this.list = list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

  this.moveUp = function(ix) {
    if(ix > -1 && ix < list.length - 1) {
      var tmp = list[ix+1];
      list[ix+1] = list[ix];
      list[ix] = tmp;
    }
  };

  this.moveDown = function(ix) {
    // similar...
  };
});
```

There were a few strange items in your code (for example did you mean `$scope.list[position] = temp;` when you wrote (`$scope.list[position = temp];`), my example isn't perfect but it should get you going on the right path. Here's the full working demo: http://jsbin.com/vatekodeje, note that in my code I use "up" to mean increasing index rather than toward the top of the page.

Also in your controller you use `position` as an index (it's not clear that it should be) and make reference to, presumably, an array called `$scope.list` when in your view you use `selectedWorkflow.Steps`. Maybe your `$scope.list` and `selectedWorkflow.Steps` are meant to be the same thing?